# Getting variable info for AlertView

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uialertview

I working with Qualcomm beacons right now and using the `visit.transmitter.name` to identify what object I want in my Parse DB. It seems to be working since the logs are displaying the data but not sure how to use `@"address: %@", [object objectForKey:@"address"]` in an alert view so its the title. My `equalTo:(@"%@",visit.transmitter.name)];` is also getting an error of `Expression Result Unused`

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"houses"];
    [query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:(@"%@",visit.transmitter.name)];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"address: %@", [object objectForKey:@"address"]);
                NSLog(@"url:: %@", [object objectForKey:@"url"]);

                NSString *displayAddress = [object objectForKey:@"address"];

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayAddress
                                                                message:@"THIS WOULD BE THE TITLE, DESCRIPTION"
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"THIS WOULD BE THE URL"]; 
                [alert show];

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stringWithFormat:

```
NSString *displayAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"address: %@", [object objectForKey:@"address"]];
```